# This method is not implemented in DominoAdapter: getCookie

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

Running **Angular Universal** on node i get this error:

> ERROR Error: This method is not implemented in DominoAdapter:
>   getCookie

Here is the line on **server.js** file:

```
var domino = __webpack_require__(349);
function _notImplemented(methodName) {
    return new Error('This method is not implemented in DominoAdapter: ' + methodName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Github issue related to this raised on their repository:

https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/536

It looks like a dependency issue, you possibly need to load the `UniversalModule` last.